# Keyword based Recomendation

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, decision-tree

I have to design a recommendation algorithm for a project in which I have following parameters :

1. The  profile of the user which contains the short description of the user along with the interest of the user
2. The description of the products taken from the review.com which contains the soecification of the product.

there is no rating or wishlist by any of the user, I just have this data and have to find the suitability of products for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but if essentially all that you have is a series of words describing a user and a series of words describing a product, then all I can think of is a simple similarity measure:

- Cosine Similarity (aka inner product)
- Dice Similarity
- Jaccard Similarity, etc.

This doesn't exactly seem like a good project, unless I'm missing something.  It doesn't matter how good your algorithm/model/etc is if you don't have a lot of data.  If this is it, it seems like you're asked to write a glorified string similarity function.

In information retrieval, one can use tf-idf (term frequency inverse-document frequency) to achieve better quality results, but it seems that you don't really have anything to work with...Hope that helps. Good luck!